# IIS7 404 Execute URL simply doesn't work

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 and Adobe ColdFusion 10.  I've set up a new website, and it's functioning properly. I've tried to set up a custom 404 page by selecting the new website, and going to the error pages panel.  I modified the 404 status code to execute a local page.  Then I went into the Feature Settings and told it to report detailed for local requests, custom for remote requests.  However, IIS is always returning the default remote 404 page.

My web.config file is about as straight forward as it gets.  The /Video/404.cfm file exists and executes properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Video/404.cfm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So I must be missing something here... How come custom 404 pages aren't working here?

Comment: Anyone have any insight here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Server 2008 R2 and CF10.  I posted a bug report [here](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3364745).